# How to enable in-editor warnings in Visual Studio Code for C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, editor, warnings

I want to enable warnings to be something like this:
[image]

So i want it to be shown in editor, not only in terminal after i compile it.
Also i installed all extensions it needs for C/C++.

Comment: Are you asking how to generate/show compiler warnings without using the compiler?

Comment: Probably not possible. I've never seen any IDE that gives you that kind of thing. Warnings come from the compiler usually.

Comment: Screenshot in post is from keil 5 and somehow i dont need to compile to show me warnings.